# ggplotly is showing the same variable twice in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

[image]

I grouped by player_name and used colour to differntiate between players. By using ggplotly player_name is shown twice. How can I avoid this?

```
ggplotly(ggplot(NBA_top, aes(season, y=player_height, colour=player_name, group=player_name)) + geom_point()+ geom_line())
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that by default `ggplotly` will show the values of all aesthetics in the tooltip. As you mapped `player_name` on both the `color` and the `group` aes the player name will show up twice.

To prevent that you could set the aesthetics to be displayed in the tooltip via the `tooltip` argument. Note that for the `color` aes you have to use `colour`.

Using a simple example based on `mtcars`:

```
library(plotly)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl), group = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

Calling `ggplotly` without setting the `tooltip` argument gives a duplicated entry in the tooltip:

```
ggploty()
```

[image]

To prevent that you could set the `tooltip` argument:

```
ggplotly(tooltip = c("x", "y", "colour"))
```

[image]